# Nuxt 3 on Ubuntu : cb.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How to fix `cb.apply is not a function` ?

```
$ node -v
v16.16.0
$ npm -v
8.11.0
$ npx -v
10.2.2
$ npx nuxi init nuxt-app
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2022-07-19T11_46_43_598Z-debug.log
L'installation de [ 'nuxi@latest' ] a échoué avec le code 1
$ cat /home/me/.npm/_logs/2022-07-19T11_46_43_598Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'nuxi@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/home/me/.npm/_npx/7138',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@5.1.0
3 info using node@v16.16.0
4 verbose npm-session bdbc314b7bc264a3
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nuxi 174ms
8 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nuxi/-/nuxi-3.0.0-rc.6.tgz 197ms
9 silly pacote tag manifest for nuxi@latest fetched in 395ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
10 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
10 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)
11 verbose cwd /home/me/code
12 verbose Linux 5.15.0-41-generic
13 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "nuxi@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "/home/me/.npm/_npx/7138" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
14 verbose node v16.16.0
15 verbose npm  v5.1.0
16 error cb.apply is not a function
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Given the first answers regarding `cb.apply is not a function`, it looks like a node_modules/NPM issues related to cache so far.

Comment: It's on a new server, there was no cache, still removing the cache didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by using `nvm`.

So, I removed nodejs:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge nodejs
```

And installed `nvm`, `nodejs`, `npm` and my Nuxt3 project with

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
$ nvm install --lts
$ npx nuxi init nuxt-app
```

Answer (score 0):

This `cb.apply is not a function` error is indirectly caused by incompatibilities between the `graceful-fs` package and an `npm` version 5.x.

```
stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
stack     at ....node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
```

at the top I can see that your `npm` version is 8.11.0 - which is fine.

However about halfway done the verbose logging shows that you have an "effective" npm version of 5.1.0

```
2 info using npm@5.1.0
3 info using node@v16.16.0
```

You clearly have old, leftover artifacts lying around, and are inadvertently picking up the incorrect version.

Recommend cleaning up node, purging, clearing cache, installing latest.

Good luck

Comment: He solved his own issue a year ago yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037828/8816585

Comment: thank you @kissu - i can see that.  i have just faced the same problem, and added my own findings - which weren't immediately clear from this thread